# Scala pattern match the same type parameter multiple times

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I want to pattern match items in a tuple, where the items have the same type, including the type parameter.  My use-case is fairly complex, but I've tried to extract a minimal example here to illustrate the problem:

```
class Foo[T] { }

val input = ( new Foo[String], new Foo[String] )

input match {
  case (a:Foo[x], b:Foo[x]) =>
    // Do things that rely on a and b having exactly the same type
}
```

But this doesn't compile, because I'm using `x` in the case statement twice.  The compile gives the following error:

```
error: x is already defined as type x
```

I've tried changing the match to pull out different type parameters for the two inputs and then testing their equality:

```
input match {
  case (a:Foo[x], b:Foo[y]) if (x == y) =>
    // Do things that rely on a and b having exactly the same type
}
```

But that doesn't compile, giving the error

```
error: not found: value x
```

Is there some Scala syntax that I can use to match two things as having the same, unspecified, type?  I am running Scala 2.9.2

Comment: the error message is misleading. the real error is that x is not a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think twice any time you catch yourself using a type or type variable in a pattern match, first because type erasure means it's not likely to work, and second because parametricity means it shouldn't. There's almost always a better solution.

In this case you could do something like the following:

```
class Foo[T] { }

val input = (new Foo[String], new Foo[String])

def doSomething[A](pair: (Foo[A], Foo[A])) = ???
```

Now `doSomething(input)` will compile, but `doSomething((new Foo[Char], new Foo[Int]))` won't (assuming you leave the type parameter on `Foo` invariant). There's still not a lot you can (honestly) do with the items in the pair, since you only know that they have the same type, so usually you'll want to add something like a type class constraint, and using a method also helps in that respect.